# Confused about perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Let's say we have 2 states of fixed parity $| + \rangle$ and $| - \rangle$ with energies $E_+$ and $E_-$ and we have a P-odd perturbing hamiltonian (on top of the original hamiltonian, $H_0$ whose eigenfunctions are the 2 above), $V_P$. According to 1st order perturbation theory, the corrections to energy for both states is zero. So in order to get any difference in energy we need to go to second order and there the correction to, say, $| + \rangle$ state is:

$$E_+^2 = \frac{|\langle-|V_P|+\rangle|^2}{E_+-E_-}$$ Also the first order correction to the wavefunction implies that $| + \rangle$ becomes:

$$| + \rangle' = | + \rangle + \frac{\langle-|V_P|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-}| - \rangle$$ Now if I want to calculate the expectation value of the energy in this $| + \rangle'$ state, I would get

$$'\langle+|H_0+V_P| + \rangle' = \frac{\langle+|V_P| - \rangle\langle-|V_P|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-}+\frac{(\langle-|V_P| + \rangle)^\dagger\langle-|V_P|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-} + E_+ + \frac{|\langle-|V_P|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}E_-$$

So the correction to the energy would be:

$$\frac{\langle+|V_P| - \rangle\langle-|V_P|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-}+\frac{(\langle-|V_P| + \rangle)^\dagger\langle-|V_P|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-} + \frac{|\langle-|V_P|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}E_-$$

So there are a few things I am confused about (please let me know if I did any calculation mistakes):

1. Why isn't the expectation value I calculated in the last equation above, equal to the predicted shift in energy by the 2nd order correction? It seems like the expectation value is also second order in $V_P$, so shouldn't they be the same?
2. If instead of $V_P$ I have a $V_{PT}$ i.e. a potential that is P,T-odd, what should I change in these calculations? In the case of parity it is clear when an expectation value is zero or not, based on the parities of the wavefunctions and the hamiltonian, but what should I do in case the potential is T-odd, too? The tricks from P-odd still applied (i.e. if a matrix element is zero for a P-odd, it is zero for a P,T-odd, too), but what further constraints do I get if I add the T-odd on top?

Thank you!

Comment: @CosmasZachos I do, but the ones so far didn't fully answer my question. I am still not sure how to approach a problem with a P,T violating potential in perturbation theory formalism.

Comment: You'll have to be specific on the explicit action of T on your potential matrix elements, or else pose an independent, precise, meaningful, unhedged, up-front question.

Comment: I hope you are not imagining you are going to convert a PT-even hamiltonian to a [Hermitian one](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501052)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. All I want to know is what is different in setting up the equations for a P-violating hamiltonian and a P,T-violating one (for example the electron EDM in an atomic Hamiltonian) within the perturbation theory approach. Mainly, if you build an experiment to search for only P or both P,T violation, you should be able to somehow differentiate between them. So I want to have a better understanding of how the hamiltonian for the 2 cases is different (given that the P,T-odd part is usually really small the perturbation theory is the right approach).

Comment: So you are considering imaginary potentials and nonhermitean Hamiltonians?  This is what I have been asking in three different ways. What states are you connecting with it? This is a question on normalizations in perturbation theory. If you have questions on T-invariance in QM, this merits a separate, ***clear*** question.

Comment: Let me give a simpler example. Here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.05316.pdf in the first paragraph after Fig. 1, they claim that for a perturbing hamiltonian that is P-violating but T-invariant the diagonal term (iW there, v* in your notation) has to be purely imaginary. I am not sure, but I assume that this implies that for a P,T-violating hamiltonian, that off diagonal term has to be purely real (or not?)? Why is that? Why is it purely imaginary in that case? And what it would actually be in the P,T-violating case?

Comment: Did you go to ref 26 the adduce? QFT texts review P,C , and T in the weak interactions. Definitely different question.

Answer (score 1):

For a 2-state system, and with the off-diagonal perturbation dictated by parity, the problem actually simplifies substantially, and you don't need to use the hidebound standard formalism you do, which led you to a mistake. So I won't play "catch my error", but, instead, slug through the easy problem directly.

Your hamiltonian is just
$$
\begin{bmatrix}E_+& v^*\\v& E_-\end{bmatrix}
$$
for $v=\langle -|V|+\rangle$ acting on 2-vectors $(1,0)^T=|+\rangle; ~~(0,1)^T=|-\rangle$.

Find the eigenvalues, to second order in $v$,
$$
\lambda_{\pm}= [E_+ + E_- \pm (E_+-E_-)\sqrt{1+4(|v|/(E_+-E_-))^2}~]~/2 \\ \approx E_{\pm} \pm {|v|^2 \over E_+ - E_-} + O(|v|^4), 
$$
your answer.

Their ***un-normalized*** eigenvectors, again to second order in $v$, are
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1\\{v\over E_+-E_- } \end{bmatrix},  \qquad \hbox{and}~~~\begin{bmatrix}{-v^*\over E_+-E_- }\\1\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
as you found.

Normalizing them will introduce $O(|v|^2)$ corrections, but without altering the eigenvalues, naturally! Check this explicitly: the most instructive exercise ever. (Do you then see you *ought* to have computed $'\langle+|H_0+V_P| + \rangle' ~/~'\!\langle+| + \rangle' $ in your calculation, instead?)

2. I suspect T-oddness would dictate imaginary off diagonal matrix elements , and so antisymmetric off diagonal terms, to preserve Hermiticity. I don't see how it would affect the first part, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually my question was about perturbation theory in general, I chose 2 levels just to avoid long sums and complicated final formulas. But your answer is really helpful. For the last part, why would the elements be imaginary? I am mainly confused by what properties does a T-odd potential have i.e. if [H,T] is not zero, what can we tell about H?

Comment: You tell me! I assumed T complex conjugates,  so  the off diagonal elements are pure imaginary, so, then antiisymmetric from hermiticity.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question:

To retrieve the second order energy correction from the correction of the wavefunction we have to take the second order correction of the wavefunction into account. It is given by (see e.g. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Second-order_and_higher-order_corrections))

$$|+\rangle'' = |+\rangle + \frac{\langle-|V_p|+\rangle}{E_+-E_-}|-\rangle - \frac{1}{2} \frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}|+\rangle$$

Then if we calculate $''\langle+|H_0+V_p|+\rangle''$ and keep only terms up to second order in $V_p$ we get additionally to the terms in the question a contribution from the second order correction of the state:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\langle+|H_0 \frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}|+\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\langle+|\frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}H_0|+\rangle = -\frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}E_+ $$

Together with the terms from the question we obtain the right correction energy
$$2\frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{E_+-E_-}+\frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{(E_+-E_-)^2}(E_--E_+)=  \frac{|\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2}{E_+-E_-}$$

where we used $\langle+|V_p|-\rangle\langle-|V_p|+\rangle = (\langle-|V_p|+\rangle)^\dagger \langle-|V_p|+\rangle = |\langle-|V_p|+\rangle|^2$ to simplify the first two terms from the question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the last step. Given that the perturbation is P-odd but not T-odd, it means that Vp is purely imaginary. So for the first equality on the last line, isn't a minus missing?